# Can I select and paste with a single operation?

Tags: cursor-motions, replace, paste

Here's my use case. I have the following text:

```
This is a [hyperlink](http://someurl.com).
```

Now I want to replace the `http://someurl.com` text with a new URL in the default register (something I've copied from somewhere else).

Normally, I would move to the line, then probably do something like this:

```
f(    # move to the opening bracket   
vi(   # select the contents of the brackets
p     # paste from the default register
```

Is there any out-of-the box way to make this faster? What I'm looking for is an operation which pastes over a motion, such as "replace-in-whatever":

```
f(    # move to the opening bracket   
pi(   # paste *over* the contents of the brackets
```

I am guessing I'd need to manually create something for this, but before I look for plugins/commands, I wanted to check if there was a standard, idiomatic way (and also ideally one which supports pasting from any register if possible!).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom operator that select and paste from any register:

```
nnoremap ,p :call <sid>opfunc_reg("<sid>select_and_paste")<cr>

" Apply current register to g@ . It's not allowed to set opfunc to s:func, i
" have to use a func argument.
"
" In function scope of normal map, v:register won't be changed by ex
" command (except :normal) ?
function! s:opfunc_reg(func)
  let &opfunc = a:func
  call feedkeys('"'. v:register .'g@')
endfunction

function! s:select_and_paste(type) abort

  " back up current register before visual selection
  let reg = v:register

  " visually select operator target.
  let vcmd = a:type ==# 'line' ? 'V' : (a:type ==# 'char' ? 'v' : "\<c-v>")
  silent exe printf('norm! `[%s`]', vcmd)

  " paste from current register
  exec 'norm! "' . reg . 'p'
endfunction
```

**Don't use it**

This operator is useless, because `vi)p` is 4 key strokes, `,pi)` is also 4 key strokes (can be reduced to 3, which is still meaningless and crazy). One should get used to `v{motion}p` style operation.

I create it only because i'm leaning to create operator that support register.

**update**

If you use custom motion or text object, a lot of things could happen between `g@` and `opfunc`, a single ex command is enough to reset `v:register`, to fix that, i have to use a global variable instead of `v:register` (not sure if it's the right way):

```
nnoremap ,p :let g:__opfunc_reg=v:register<cr>:set opfunc=<sid>select_and_paste<cr>g@

function! s:select_and_paste(type) abort

  " visually select operator target.
  let vcmd = a:type ==# 'line' ? 'V' : (a:type ==# 'char' ? 'v' : "\<c-v>")
  silent exe printf('norm! `[%s`]', vcmd)

  " paste from current register
  exec 'norm! "' . g:__opfunc_reg . 'p'
endfunction
```

Comment: The nested ternary could become a dict, and you could `get` with a default value. The paste could be `exec 'put' reg`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Not sure the meaning of default value here,  `:put` is linewise, can't be used here.

Comment: Ah youre right. For the dict, something like `get({'line': 'V', 'char': 'v'}, a:type, '<C-v>')`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That's a little weird, i shall keep it in mind, it's the first time i see it. I was thinking you mean something like : `{'line': 'V', 'char': 'v', 'block' : "\<c-v>"}[a:type]`.

Comment: i couldnt remember if block was available; i was just going off the ternary. I would definitely prefer your version if it works.